# how to fix Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:port on linux

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

hi i create project with .net core.my project connect to  other project to get services.i read docker-compose and set network for projects.in windows os my project correctly connect to other project and get services.i set ip `127.0.0.1` to connect to other project.in linux i see ip docker container projects like this

```
docker network inspect my_project_net
```

and see

```
 "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
 "IPv6Address": ""
```

and get this error when my project connect to other projects

```
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:port // port is 105
```

how i can cast this port to 127.0.0.1 or run correctly my project
thanks for read my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set container_name in docker-compose to environment project that connects to another project for example :

```
  version: '3.3'
     
    services:
      proj1:
        container_name: proj-1
        image:  ...
        ports:
          - "5002:5002" 
          - "8443:8443"
        environment:
          - ConnectionString=Data Source=127.0.0.1,14330;Initial Catalog=db;
User  id=sa;Password=******; // in docker-compose you must use (container_name) mssql insted 127.0.0.1
          - ConnectionString=Data Source=mssql,14330;Initial Catalog=db;
User  id=sa;Password=******; // true 
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mssqlservice
        restart: always
      mssqlservice:
        image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU3-ubuntu-18.04'
        container_name: mssql
        environment:
          ACCEPT_EULA: Y
          MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: ******
        volumes:
          - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql
        expose:
          - 1433
        ports:
          - "14330:1433"
        restart: always
    volumes:
      sqlvolume:
        driver: local
        name: mssqldata
```